# How to make the indents by Vim look consistent in other software?(e.g.. Textmate, textwrangler)

Tags: vim, macvim, indentation

I use MacVim to edit my code. The indents **look pretty good in** Vim,Emacs and textedit.
But they **look horrible in** Textmate2, textwrangler.

**How to make the indents by Vim look consistent in other software?(e.g.. Textmate, textwrangler)?**

This is my vim setting about tap:

```
"auto indent of new line accoring to the previous line
set autoindent 
"smart indent for c program
set smartindent
" add tab of new line
set smarttab
" define smarttab length
set shiftwidth=4
```

[image: vim]
[image: emacs]
[image: textedit]
[image: textmate]
[image: textragg]

Comment: what is your question about,can you be more constructive ??

Comment: Perhaps this is what you're looking for? http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Converting_tabs_to_spaces

Comment: @Daan Thx, that's work for me :) So the best way is to use space instead of real tab??? You may leave it as answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like those programs don't all interpret tabs in the same way. The easiest way to make sure it looks the same in all texteditors is to only use spaces:

```
set tabstop=4
set shiftwidth=4
set expandtab
```

You might also want to use `:retab`. Checkout [Converting tabs to spaces](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Converting_tabs_to_spaces) for more info.

Comment: I always use these settings. When you program in a language where indentation has a meaning (such as python, haskell), different kinds of tabs can lead to bugs.